# Access to another model throws error Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

so i have the following controller:

```
    class ForwardsController extends AppController
{
    public $uses = array('Offer', 'ExceptionUrl', 'Forward', 'Brand', 'MyModel, Website');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler', 'HasOffers', 'BloglicHelper', 'Paginator', /*'DebugKit.Toolbar'*/);
    public $categories = array();
    public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'), 'Paginator');

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

}
```

Now when i try to do the following:

```
     $web = $this->Website->find('all');
```

i get the following error:

```
2013-09-09 10:08:14 Error: Fatal Error (1): Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the Website model before find.

```
$this->loadModel('Website'); // add this line
$web = $this->Website->find('all');
```